# How to flush an RTOS queue and prevent further posting on a device disconnect event?

Tags: rtos, freertos

In the following code

- `SendMessage()` is the API called by the user to send a message over USB
- `Task()` is the thread created in `init()` that reads the queue and calls the low level usb function to send a message
- `UsbConnected()` e `UsbDisconnecte()` are two functions called by another thread when the a USB device is connected and disconnected respectively.

I want to implement the following behaviour:
 - When the `UsbDisconnet()` function exits, the queue `QueueA` must be empty and no further messages can be post on the queue by calling `SendMessage()`

My best solution that uses FreeRTOS API is listed below.

There are two things that I do not like of my solution

- It uses an `xQueueSend()` inside a Mutex.
- The while loop used to clear the queue.

Does a better solution exists?

```
void UsbhOut(Message_t );
int UsbConnected;
SemaphoreHandle_t MutexA;
QueueHandle_t QueueA;

void init(void)
{
  MutexA = xSemaphoreCreateMutex();
  QueueA = xQueueCreate(sizeof(Message_t), 10);
  UsbConnected = 0;

  xTaskCreate(Task, "", 200, NULL, 1, NULL);
}

void UsbConnected(void)
{
  UsbConnected = 1;
}


int SendMessage(Message_t Message)
{
  xSemaporeTake(MutexA, portMAX_DELAY);

  if(!UsbConnected)
  {
    xSemaphoreGive(MutexA);
    return -1;
  }

  xQueueSend(QueueA, &Message, portMAX_DELAY);
  xSemaporeGive(MutexA);
  return 0;
}

void Task(void * pvParameters)
{
  Message_t Message;
  while(1)
  {
    xQueueReceive(QueueA, &Message, portMAX_DELAY);

    UsbhOut(Message);

  }
}


void UsbDisconneted(void)
{
  Message_t DummyMessage;

  xSemaporeTake(MutexA, portMAX_DELAY);
  UsbConnected = 0;
  xSemaporeGive(MutexA);

  while(xQueueReceive(QueueA, &DummyMessage, 0) == pdTRUE);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the xQueueReset() API function - it might help:
http://www.freertos.org/a00018.html#xQueueReset

Comment: Great! I didn't see that API. However, what about the issue with the Mutex? Do you think that there is a way to avoid it?